# Angularjs controller calling WebAPI always results in failure callback

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI endpoint like in code Snippet 1 and AngularJS like in Code Snippet 2.  I traced the code to the WebAPI and the post method is called.  The model binding also binds to the correct model from the request body.  It also returns OK status.  In the Network Summary tab of the Internet Explorer's Developer Tools (F12), the Result column is 200 and the json data is in the response body of the Network Detail tab.  However, the failure callback is always executed in the consultFactory.save() in the AngularJS controller.  Does anyone know why?  Thanks.

SNIPPET 1

```js
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] ConsultRequest consultRequest) {
  if (consultRequest == null)
    return BadRequest("consult request cannot be null");
  var response = TheRepository.GetConsultsWithDetails(consultRequest);

  if (response == null)
    return NotFound();

  response = response
    .OrderBy(r => r.RequestDateTime)
    .Take(consultRequest.Take);

  return Ok(response);
}
```

SNIPPET 2

```js
function getConsults(consultRequest) {
  $log.log('consultRequest', consultRequest);

  debugger;

  consultFactory.save(consultRequest,
    function(data) {
      $log.log('consult-list.component.getConsults() ::: succeeded in retrieving data from consult factory', data);
      $log.log('consult-list.component.getConsults() ::: total consults', data.length);
      vm.consults = data;
      vm.isBusy = false;
      vm.ActiveCount = ($filter("filter")(data, {
        orderStatus: 'ACTIVE'
      })).length;
      vm.PendingCount = ($filter("filter")(data, {
        orderStatus: 'PENDING'
      })).length;
      vm.PartialResultsCount = ($filter("filter")(data, {
        orderStatus: 'PARTIAL RESULTS'
      })).length;
    },
    function(response) {
      $log.log('consult-list.component.getConsults() ::: failed to retrieve data from consult factory');
      vm.errorMessage = response.statusText + "\r\n";
      vm.isBusy = false;
    });
}
```

SNIPPET3

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('consults', ['ngResource'])
        .factory('consultFactory', consultFactory);

    consultFactory.$inject = ['$resource', 'appSettings'];

    function consultFactory($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.nwicWebApi + "consults/:consultId",
                null,
                {
                    'update': { method: 'PUT', params: {consultId: '@consultId' } }
                });
    };

}());
```

Response Header
[image: Response Header]

Comment: Why you have `method:'PUT'` ? Shouldn't it be `POST` ?

Comment: Angular expects `application/json` result from API's, can you verify the response header is correct and the data is a valid json?

Comment: It's a custom PUT method. It's not use in this case. The .save() of $resource is used to POST to the WebAPI endpoint.